# How to delete children in JPA correctly with nullable=false columns

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have the following schema in my code:

```java
class Parent {

    long id;
    
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "parent", //parent is in Child class
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        targetEntity = Child.class)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @Builder.Default
    Set<Child> children;
    
    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
}

class Child {

    long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_child_parent"))
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    Parent parent;
    
    // parent is in GrandChild class
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @Builder.Default
    Set<GrandChild> grandChildren;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean deleted;
}

class GrandChild {

    long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Child.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_grandchild_child"))
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    Child parent;
}
```

What I want to do is, I want to find existing entities (parent entity) in database, delete its children (child and grandchild), and then create a new child and grandchild entities and assign to the parent and save.

```java
// service class
public Parent mainMethod(long parentId) {
    Parent parent = parentRepository.findById(parentId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception(String.format("Not found %s", parentId)));
        
    parent.getChildren().clear();
    parentRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);
    
    // for simplicity, ignore grandchild
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setParent(parent);
    parent.getChildren().add(child);
    
    parent = parentRepository.save(parent);

    someAuditRepository.save(parent);
    return parent;
}
```

Just when I return from the function, I am receiving the following error (note that, since I have simplified some fields, the PLSQL statement is kind of long)

```
2022-08-10 12:47:25.313 ERROR 4744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "deleted" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (499881, 39924, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "deleted" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (499881, 39924, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

I know that it happens because the `@Column(nullable = false)` in deleted field of Child class. However, I need this nullable property. How can I delete existing entries completely, and then add new ones without facing this error? Also, I do not know at what point I am receiving this error. There are several invoked methods and what I know that it happens after the return statement.

There is no "Transactional" attribute on the method. The method is called from a REST endpoint directly (Rest controller calls the service method, that's it).

```java
// Rest controller
public ResponseEntity<Parent> someMethod(@PathVariable long parentId) {
     Parent created = service.mainMethod(parentId);
     return ResponseEntity.ok(created);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not like this solution, but this is work:

```
public Parent mainMethod(long parentId) {
    Parent parent = parentRepository.findById(parentId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception(String.format("Not found %s", parentId)));
        
    Parent updatedParent = new Parent();
    updatedParen.setId(parent.getId())
    ...
    // map all values from parent to updatedParent
    
    
    Child child = new Child();
    child.setParent(updatedParent);
    Set<Child> childSet = new HashSet<>();
    childSet.add(child);
    parent.setChildren(childSet);
    
    updatedParent = parentRepository.save(updatedParent);

    return updatedParent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. @k-nikita I have found that I have an AUD table and in that table, I set deleted value nullable to false. So, although the original table is Ok, the audit table was wrong. That is why this bug was happening after `return` statement. So, altering the audit table with deleted nullable is allowed solved my problem